# any sample code for backtrace on ARM9?

Tags: arm, stack-trace, embedded-linux, backtrace

i want to write a code which will work like backtrace utility on ARM9 architecture.

i did come across the code [back trace for ulibc in arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052252/back-trace-for-ulibc-in-arm).
But from above code i want to know the details of data structure layout and parameter used in above code.
Can anyone throw some light on the above.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In glibc it's defined in dlfcn/dlfcn.h and looks like

```
/* Structure containing information about object searched using
   `dladdr'.  */
typedef struct
{
  __const char *dli_fname;      /* File name of defining object.  */
  void *dli_fbase;              /* Load address of that object.  */
  __const char *dli_sname;      /* Name of nearest symbol.  */
  void *dli_saddr;              /* Exact value of nearest symbol.  */
} Dl_info;
```