# Stacktrace arm-linux-gcc

Tags: gcc, stack-trace, arm

I want to dump stacktrace of my program as the example demonstrated at [backtrace[3]](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace), but I got result below, instead.

I am using **linux 2.6**, and **arm-linux-gcc 4.3.2**.

Running:
`arm-linux-gcc prog.c -o prog -rdynamic`

the result is:

> backtrace() returned 1 addresses
>
> /lib/ld-linux.so.3 [0x40025000]

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Thanks

---

I don't have any problem with gcc, But I cant get traces with arm-linux-gcc.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [GCC ARM Options documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html), you need to pass the *-mapcs-frame* option to GCC to generate stack frames on the ARM platform.

> *-mapcs-frame* 
>   Generate a stack frame that is compliant with the ARM Procedure Call Standard for all functions, even if this is not strictly necessary for correct execution of the code. Specifying *-fomit-frame-pointer* with this option causes the stack frames not to be generated for leaf functions. The default is *-mno-apcs-frame*.

This was pointed out to me in a comment to my [**Linux specific answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1925461/203667) to [How to generate a stacktrace when my gcc C++ app crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77005/203667), which you may also find useful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I didn't get expected result (there is no messages for backtrace_symbols), I am working on device is _mini 2440_

Comment: It is possible that your version of **glibc** or **uclibc** doesn't contain a working implementation of `backtrace()` for your architecture.  In a project I worked on once, we had to roll our own `backtrace()` because the existing one wasn't fully implemented.  If this is the case, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2536136/203667) may be of some assistance.

Comment: maybe! linux kernel will dump stack-trace when some problem is occurred, I check your recommendation. thanks for your comment @jschmier